# Clear out dropdown value once another drodown value is changed in vba access?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have three combo box controls(MFG, Code, and GrpID) in my VBA access form. Once the user selects an option from the first combo box (MFG), rest of combo boxes give me available options. But I need to do some validation i.e. what if the user decided to change the value of first combo box? The values of rest combo box should be cleared. All I need to do is once the first combo box is changed the second and third combo box need to be cleared out or at least set to focus on them so that users will realize that they can't use old values as first value is cleared in the first combo box. I added a code block 'AfterUpdate for first combo box as shown below:

```
Private Sub MFG_AfterUpdate()
   Code.Value = " "
   GrpID.Value = 0    
End Sub
```

The problem after writing above code is: they don't get empty until they(Code and GrpID) get clicked. In other words, I need to click them to empty them every time I change the value of MFG. Can anyone direct me how do I clear them or at least focus them?

Comment: Maybe you need a Requery? Also, if that event isn't working try the `Change` Event

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior with the data you provided (combo boxes instantly clear when the AferUpdate event fires when I try this). Note that the AfterUpdate event fires when either changing a combo box through the dropdown, or when you tab out of a combo box you changed through typing. Can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Set the combo to null to wipe any displayed value in them;

```
Me.Code = Null
Me.GrpID = Null
```

This assumes your combo controls are called the same as your field names.

Edit for clarity: Including the Me. makes sure your are changing the form control values. If your field names are the same as the controls then Access will change the underlying field values, and as you have discovered on your form these aren't reflected until you click in that fields bound control.

Comment: I doubt that solves the problem the OP is having, since (at least in my setup) `""` or `" "` or `0` all are set instanly too. Yes, setting them to `Null` is better, but if you think this fixes the OPs problem, please explain why, else, comment. My best guess is that the `On Update` function fires late in the OPs setup, in which case this will make no difference, but as said, can't replicate so can't test

Comment: This should work in the after update of the first combo box, I suspect his use of the field names rather than the referring to the current forms control object by using Me. is the cause of his problem, so I think my answer still stands.

Comment: That's useful information to include in the answer (it will help the user avoid the error again, and it's useful to know the `Me.` is the relevant part, and not the `Null`). I doubt it's true, though, since the `Me.` can be omitted if there are no conflicting variables (just like `Application.` in most situations), and if there were, you would probably not get this behavior (the code working, but just late). But as said, can't replicate so can't test, we will have to wait for the OP.

Comment: @Minty: Sorry for late reply. The name and control source got different names and this is a very old program so I am wondering if anything breaks if i try to rename them. In addition, I need to validate these combo boxes not null. Meaning, they can't be null before clicking a 'Validate' btn. I need to clear out other 2 combo values just to make sure that users don't keep the stale values from  first chosen option of the first combo box. So, as soon as first combo box value changes, other two should clear out so that user will enter new values

Comment: Okay - then in order to set the Controls value use the syntax `Me.YourControlName = Null` . When you type the `Me.` you should get intellisense to list the available control names.

Comment: I got debug error which highlights yellow in this line while doing `Me.YourControlName = Null`.

Comment: Sorry I was only indicating the syntax, replace `YourControlName` with your actual control name on your form.